# Can't connect to Ubuntu Server docker container from Windows on local network

Tags: docker

I'm starting to learn Docker.

For practice, I have set up an Nginx container on Ubuntu Server (separate PC).

Used this command `docker run -it -d -p 8080:80 nginx`

Then I did `curl` on it's home network IP (`192.168.1.38:8080`) and it worked fine. Showed Nginx starter page.

But then I tried to see that starter page on Windows, and `curl 192.168.1.38:8080` didn't work there. It didn't open in the browser either. Gave ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

I have tried to do it the other way around:

Set up the same Nginx container on a Windows machine and tried to curl it's IP:8080 from Ubuntu Server machine and it worked.

So seems like Windows lets access its IP:8080 from other devices, and Ubuntu doesn't.

Comment: Hello @slayoffer. I need a better explanation here in order to help you. What do you mean by "it's home network"? Where do you have the container running? Explain better your setup.

Comment: Is there some firewall running on your Ubuntu machine e.g. `iptables`? Are other applications perhaps using the port? Check with `sudo ss -tlpn`? Can you ping the ubuntu machine from the Windows machine?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu server version that you are using?

Comment: Hi @NunoOliveira! Home network is my WiFi network at home. Ubuntu Server machine has 192.168.1.38 ip and Windows machine has 192.168.1.87 ip. Container runs on Ubuntu. Ubuntu Server version is 22.

Comment: Hey @Garuno. I only have ufw, but i have added there port 8080. I also have Plex running on port 32400 on Ubuntu and i can easiliy access it from Windows. As for ping - sure, i can ping Ubuntu IP from Windows.

Comment: I have also tried to go with "--network host" option and after that i can curl Ubuntu IP from Windows. But this option only works with port 80.

Comment: Can you try to do this command in Windows: `telnet 192.168.1.38 8080`?

Comment: @NunoOliveira i have tried to connect it via Telnet now with stopped container and it gave connection error right away (of course). Then i started the Nginx Ubuntu container again (on port 8080) and Telnet thought for about 20 seconds and then gave connection error. Seems like it found it but couldnt connect.

Comment: Interesting. What is the Ubuntu server version that you are using?

Comment: For example when i do "curl 192.168.1.38:32400" on Windows it works. Thats the Plex ip on Ubuntu machine. Telnet for 192.168.1.38 32400 also works.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64. I have also Apache server running on it for Nextcloud.

Comment: Can you try to add at Ubuntu Server: `sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp`?

Comment: And then place the output of `sudo ufw status` here.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help either. Here is the current ufw status http://joxi.ru/nAyvqRt9EybkrZ

Comment: @NunoOliveira actually that did help! All i needed to do was to restart the server. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can you please upvote my answer(s)?

Comment: @NunoOliveira it says i dont have enough reputation to upvote yet, but it recorded my attempt to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp` on your Ubuntu Server should fix this issue.